# Python iterate over csv rows with multiple factors

Tags: python, csv, iteration

I am looking to summarize data by Unit, Period and SupplierID. For each Unique Unit and Period Combo return the SupplierID with the largerst Amount. This would sum the amounts for a SupplierID in a given Unit/period.
So in the case below it should return:

5400,6 - 7957.33

6300,7 - 9801.10

I would like to accomplish this by iterating over the data WITHOUT using Numpy or Pandas as I am trying to understand the logic.
I am stuck on the logic part, how to iterate over this and store the data. Below I was trying dictionaries but not sure that is the best way...
Here is a short data sample:

```
cv = "Unit,SupplierID,ReceivedPeriod,Amount/n5400,0213123,6,3450.87/n5400,0521332,6,5902.21/n5400,0213123,6,4506.46/n6300,0293899,7,9801.10/n6300,0381923,7,6203.76"
line = cv.split("/n")
d = {}
for l in line:
    unit,id,period,amount = l.split(",")
    k1 = unit + "," + period
    k2 = id
    if k1 in d:
        if k2 in d[k1]:
        up = d[k1][id]
        nup = float(amount) + float(up)
        d[k1][id] = round(nup, 2)
    else:
        d[k1] = {[id]:amount}
```

The way I am going about this seems to complicated, is there a better way to go about this when iterating rows?

Comment: Does the posted code work, and you're trying to improve it? Or does it fail, in which case please tell us how it fails to do what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your string to use real newlines instead of your fake "/n", so the code can easily move to reading a file.  I also added code to skip over the header line.  This would be modestly easier using the "csv" module to parse the string.  It would also be a bit shorter by using `DefaultDict` instead of a straight dict.

```
cv = "Unit,SupplierID,ReceivedPeriod,Amount\n5400,0213123,6,3450.87\n5400,0521332,6,5902.21\n5400,0213123,6,4506.46\n6300,0293899,7,9801.10\n6300,0381923,7,6203.76"
d = {}
for l in cv.splitlines():
    unit,id,period,amount = l.split(",")
    if unit == 'Unit':
        continue
    amount = float(amount)
    k1 = unit + "," + period
    if k1 in d:
        if id in d[k1]:
            d[k1][id] += amount
        else:
            d[k1][id] = amount
    else:
        d[k1] = {id:amount}
print(d)

for k,v in d.items():
    largest = max(v.values())
    print(k,largest)
```

Output:

```
{'5400,6': {'0213123': 7957.33, '0521332': 5902.21}, '6300,7': {'0293899': 9801.1, '0381923': 6203.76}}
5400,6 7957.33
6300,7 9801.1
```